# Estimate a parameter following a zero-bounded triangular distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, mixed-model, maximum-likelihood, random-variable

Say I have to estimate a model with a parameter $\beta$ that follows a parametric distribution. For instance, let's say that I want this parameter to follow a normal distribution, that is to say: $\beta\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$. Here the parameters I will estimate will be $\mu$ and $\sigma$. When writing it in statistical software one way to estimate said model is using simulated maximum likelihood as it was done by [Macfadden & Train (2000)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/1099-1255%28200009/10%2915%3A5%3C447%3A%3AAID-JAE570%3E3.0.CO%3B2-1). In order to do that, you can sample from a standard normal distribution ($v$) and construct the following transformation: $$\beta= \mu + \sigma \cdot v $$
which will allow you to estimate the $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of the (assumed!) normal distribution of $\beta$.

The same can be done if we assume that for example, $\beta$ follows a Uniform distribution: $\beta\sim U(a,b)$ where we need to find the parameters that describe its range $a$ and $b$. In order to estimate it we can sample from a uniform distribution ($u$) and use the transformation:
$$\beta = a + b \cdot u  $$

Even further, we can create a parameter that follows a symmetric triangular distribution with parameters $c$ and $d$ by using the following transformation that uses two Uniform distributions $u_1$ and $u_2$.

$$\beta = c + d \cdot\left( \frac{u_1 + u_2}{2}\right) $$

Finally, **here is my question.** I would like to have a parameter that follows a zero-bounded (or restricted) symmetric triangular distribution it was implemented by [León & Miguel (2017)](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/app.20160140). With *zero-bound*, we are saying that the domain will be only for negative values. As they show in their online appendix [Figure A.3](https://www.aeaweb.org/content/file?id=2907) (the figure shows a distribution bounded from below so the domain is positive, but it is the same idea, but for the negative domain.).

However, the way that I need to generate the transformation using Uniforms distributions in order to get a zero-bounded (or restricted) symmetric triangular distribution is not immediately clear to me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Most of this question appears to be unnecessary, because nothing preceding "Even further" is relevant to what follows.   With your final formula you give a procedure to generate  draws from a "symmetric triangular distribution."  Just apply it!  What needs to be said?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @whuber. I am sorry if I gave too extensive context. Regarding the formulae provided, I gave a transformation for a triangular distribution with a domain over the entire real line. I am confused, however, about how to make it *zero-bounded* (to constrain its domain to the negative values only).

Comment: Suppose, to be concrete--without unnecessarily restricting the setting--that the $u_i$ in the last formula are independent uniform random variables over the interval $[0,1].$ Then--obviously--their mean is supported on $[0,1]$ as well, whence $\beta$ has $100\%$ chance of lying in the interval $[c, c+d]$ (equivalent to $[c+d,c]$ for negative $d$). This is an interval of negative numbers when both $c$ and $c+d$ are negative.  Because it is *never* "the entire real line," I truly do not understand your comment.

Comment: I understand your point. As you mentioned, if $c$ and $d$ happen to be negative, it produces an interval of negative values. However, if $c$ and $d$ are positive, it creates an interval of positive values. As $c$ and $d$ result from an unconstrained optimization problem, they can have both positive and negative values. So my question is, how can I restrict the produced distribution so it only takes positive (or negative) values _before_ estimating the model.

Comment: Imposing a distribution with a negative domain makes sense, for example, for **cost** or **price** coefficients because we assume its effect on utility is negative. Mainly, because we believe nobody wants to pay more for a given product, the assumption is questionable, I know, (brand effects, etc.), but this is primarily the underlying idea.

Comment: Examples of distributions that have negative domains are for example a negative log-normal distribution which is vastly used in this kind of literature. At the cost of having to deal with unreasonably long tails for the estimated parameters sometimes. This is why in the article by León & Miguel (2017) they used what they called a _restricted triangular distribution_.

Comment: You need to provide details of the model and its estimation before anyone could possibly provide specific advice.